# Paginate tables separately on same page?

Tags: python, django, django-tables2

I'm using tables2 for django. I have my tables (mostly) working, just some fine tuning of the rendering, but the data is all there. The trouble that I'm having is that I have several tables on one html page. Some of the tables might have four records, while others might have several hundred. When I paginate I get the "Next" box at the bottom of the tables that have more records. However, when I press the button, I can see that it's trying to go to page #2 of some of the tables that only have one page and giving me an error. Is there a way that I can ID each of my tables? Ideally, a user could be on page #1 for Table1, page #15 for Table2, page #73 for Table3, etc.

Comment: Did you try adding a prefix for each table? https://django-tables2.readthedocs.io/en/stable/pages/query-string-fields.html?highlight=multiple#query-string-fields

Comment: Not sure how to mark a comment as an answer, but this was exactly what I was looking for. Thank you!